# Creating a polyline from point data that represents multiple linear features in ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have a problem where I have to somewhow create a polyline feature class in ArcGIS 10.0 from points that were collected in the field using a Trimble GeoXT that represent the start and end of multiple linear features such as stone walls, wire fences, etc... The Trimble GeoXT collects the date and the exact time that the point for the start and end of the linear feature was collected. The idea is I am walking a forest boundary line where sometimes there is a stone wall that starts and follows the boundary, but then stops and there is nothing for 20 feet or so and then a wire fence starts and follows the boundary and may end or transition into a stone wall, something else or nothing at all along this forest boundary line.

I need a python script that can draw a line from the start of one linear feature, such as a stone wall, to its end point and stop and then do the same thing for all the other types of linear features (stone walls, wire fences, barb wire fences and virginia rail to be exact).

Is there any way this is possible? I am not very skilled using Python scripting.

The Points To Lines tool in ArcGIS 10.0 only draws a single line through every single point regardless of what type of linear feature the point represents and continues this single line where there is no fence. The Points To Lines tool also does not cary over any of the attribute data that is associated with the original point layer.

I hope I have provided enough information. Please ask for more information if needed.

Comment: Could you also add how you define your different objects in the point shapefile, e.g. paste the first few rows of your attribute table here?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the "Line Field" option in the Points to Line tool, add a unique value to each feature in the point attirbute table, and have it make a separate line for each feature.

If it isn't working, I think ETGeowizards and xtools both have a free tool that will convert points into grouped lines.  There was another tool on Arcscripts called "Attributed Lines From Points"that did this very well in 9.2/9.3, but I haven't seen a version of it for 10 yet.